# LESS CSS Programming

Tags: html, css, less

I am using an "OPEN SUSE-LINUX". There is no compiler available for less css in linux. For ex. "simple-less compiler" is not working in linux as it has .exe file.
So there is some difficulty which i came across. 
So anyone can give me a basic info of how to use LESS CSS without using compiler. There is website for these kind of information but it have lots of ambiguity. Also need html file along with LESS CSS.
So clearly needed a html file which is linked with any less css minified version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Node module: https://npmjs.org/package/less

```
npm install -g less
lessc styles.less styles.css
```

If you use PHP as server-side language you can use the PHP compiler http://leafo.net/lessphp/

Comment: no i am working with java as a back end programming. I only need less css in front end. Actually i want to replace .css file with .less extension now

Comment: And m also using net beans 7.3 ide. There is no file name with less extension what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to compile the less code. I don't know if suse has package for gem/rubygems, but you can install gem and then use gem to install less.

How to install rubygems is more a OS question, programming. So StackOverflow may not be the right forum, but to point you in the right direction:

First hit on google for "less css suse" find an Ubundu solution. First line is dist-specific and the last line may require different paths on suse:
http://www.edmondscommerce.co.uk/less-css/less-css-installation-on-ubuntu-10-10/

```
sudo apt-get install rubygems1.8 ruby1.8-dev (ubuntu/debian)

sudo gem install rubygems-update
sudo gem update rubygems
sudo gem install less

sudo ln -s /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/lessc /usr/bin/
```

Comment: Ubuntu != Suse, so `apt-get` will not be available (and the paths will probably be different).

Comment: I know, did not try and insinuate that it's the same. That's why I wrote about the OS install question, and highlighted that the first line of the code is debian/ubuntu specific. But I'll add a line to clarify that the code is not copy-paste

Comment: OK i understood that. But now there is another issue which i faced: "I am developing a java project and i used css file in front end but now i want to work on "LESS CSS" technology instead of simple css. I have been uses Net-beans ide for that. But there is a no option for .less files". please help me.